# Why does "DalliError: No server available" keep appearing in the logs, although I'm using redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, memcached

I'm running a modified version of Sharetribe on a server. Here's a part of code of Sharetribe:

```
  config.cache_store =
    if ENV["redis_host"].present?
      Readthis.fault_tolerant = true
      [:readthis_store, {
         redis: { host: ENV["redis_host"],
         [............]
       }]
    else
      [:dalli_store, (ENV["MEMCACHIER_GREEN_SERVERS"] || "").split(","), {
         username: ENV["MEMCACHIER_GREEN_USERNAME"],
         [............]
       }]
    end
```

On my production I use redis. Not memcached.

```
  RAILS_ENV=production redis_host=localhost redis_port=6379 redis_db=0  rails server [.....]
```

However, in logs on production this keeps appearing as if I was using memcached:

```
DalliError: No server available
```

Why? How to fix it and do I have too? Is this an error or warning that can be ignored?

In Gemfile I have `gem "dalli", "~> 2.7.6`

Comment: "Dalli is a high performance pure Ruby client for accessing memcached servers.". Why do you have it in your gemfile in the first place?

Comment: @max because on staging I use memcached

Comment: Thats not really a good idea. You want to have parity. https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

Comment: @max my question isn't about that.

Comment: Are your storing your sessions in memcached? I.e. what is your config for `Rails.application.config.session_store`

Comment: Or do you call `Rails.cache.dalli` anywhere in your code?